# CountDownLatch: object not locked by thread before wait()

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to pause the main thread until the other thread finishes.
I tried `CountDownLatch` and semaphore. but none of them worked. I got the same error for both.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Code

```
 public void testCountDownLatch(){
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latch Released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    try {
        countDownLatch.wait();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Yes! I am free now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I tried to search for a few hours and was able to understand the cause of the error (`wait()` won't know if the `countdown()` gets called before it, in that case it would wait forever) but I couldn't able to understand how to fix it:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. You should call `await`, not `wait`. See [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for example code.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the wrong method. You need to use `await()` instead of `wait()`.

[`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) is a method from `Object` and that method requires to `synchronize` over that object. Other synchronizers are normally preferred over `Object#wait`. Objects locked with `Object#wait` can be woken up with [`Object#notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) or [`Object#notifyAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/../../lang/Object.html#notifyAll()).

[`await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()) is a method of `CountDownLatch` and it waits for the `CountDownLatch` to count down (using [`CountDownLatch#countDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown())) to 0.

If you use [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (basically the opposite of `CountDownLatch`), you can aquire (increase the count of the semaphore by 1 if its limit has not been reached yet) it with [`Semaphore#aquire`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire()) and release (decrese the count of the semaphore) with [`Semaphore#release`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release()).

Aside from that, it seems like you are developing an Android app. You should **never** block the main thread of an Android application (or the UI thread of any graphical application) [as this will block your UI and result in `Application not responding` notices](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads). Blocking the UI (thread) means that your app will not respond to any UI events (like the user clivking on a button). If you need to do blocking stuff, you should do that in a background/worker thread. You should also refrain from doing IO operations in the main thread for that reason (android even blocks network operations in the main thread).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaining the difference between the two

Comment: @nikhil123 It seems like you are using Android. Never ever block/wait in the main thread (see my note).

Answer (score -1):

1.The thread should start
2.It should be await and not wait.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).